# Copy a transaction_id to all previously timestamped rows with the same user_id using sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with google analytics attribution data in bigquery. In order to hard code different attribution models, for every transaction I would first  like to attribute that transaction by a visitor to every previous visit to the website by that distinct visitor_id.

To do that, I would like to copy the transaction id to all previous rows of that user data (rows are ordered by visitor_id and visit_number).

For example, I may have a table like this:

```
| Visitor_ID | Visit_Number | Transaction_ID |
----------------------------------------------
|     A      |       1      |       null     |
|     A      |       2      |       null     |
|     A      |       3      |       F1245    |
```

I would like to end up with a table like the following:

```
 | Visitor_ID | Visit_Number | Transaction_ID |
----------------------------------------------
|     A      |       1      |       F1245    |
|     A      |       2      |       F1245    |
|     A      |       3      |       F1245    |
```

However if I have a table like the following:

```
| Visitor_ID | Visit_Number | Transaction_ID |
----------------------------------------------
|     B      |       1      |       null     |
|     B      |       2      |       null     |
|     B      |       3      |       G1245    |
|     B      |       4      |       null     |
```

I would like to end up with a table where only the visits previous to the transaction take credit for the transaction:

```
| Visitor_ID | Visit_Number | Transaction_ID |
----------------------------------------------
|     B      |       1      |       G1245    |
|     B      |       2      |       G1245    |
|     B      |       3      |       G1245    |
|     B      |       4      |       null     |
```

Is there any way to do this using SQL queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

This version covers the case when same Visitor has few transactions - so they assigned to respective visit_numbers

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 1 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 2 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 3 AS Visit_Number, 'F1245' AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 4 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 5 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 6 AS Visit_Number, 'F1246' AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 7 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS Visitor_ID, 1 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS Visitor_ID, 2 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS Visitor_ID, 3 AS Visit_Number, 'G1245' AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'B' AS Visitor_ID, 4 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID
)
SELECT
  Visitor_ID, 
  Visit_Number, 
  Transaction_ID AS originalTransaction_ID, 
  SUBSTR(MIN(CONCAT(CAST(1000000 + Visit_Number AS STRING), Transaction_ID)) OVER(win), 7) AS Transaction_ID
FROM Input
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY Visitor_ID ORDER BY Visit_Number DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
ORDER BY Visitor_ID, Visit_Number
```

Result is as below

```sql
Visitor_ID  Visit_Number    originalTransaction_ID  Transaction_ID   
A           1               null                    3F1245   
A           2               null                    3F1245   
A           3               F1245                   3F1245   
A           4               null                    6F1246   
A           5               null                    6F1246   
A           6               F1246                   6F1246   
A           7               null                    null     
B           1               null                    3G1245   
B           2               null                    3G1245   
B           3               G1245                   3G1245   
B           4               null                    null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `MAX` with a window clause. Here is an example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 1 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 2 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS Visitor_ID, 3 AS Visit_Number, 'F1245' AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS Visitor_ID, 1 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS Visitor_ID, 2 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS Visitor_ID, 3 AS Visit_Number, 'G1245' AS Transaction_ID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS Visitor_ID, 4 AS Visit_Number, NULL AS Transaction_ID
)
SELECT
  * EXCEPT (Transaction_ID),
  MAX(Transaction_ID) OVER (
    PARTITION BY Visitor_ID ORDER BY Visitor_ID DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  ) AS Transaction_ID
FROM Input
ORDER BY Visitor_ID, Visit_Number ASC;
```

Comment: I think this only works if `TransactionID` is ordered? If you put `'H1245'` in the final `NULL`, all of B will have `H1245`?

Comment: I made the assumption that there is only one distinct `Transaction_ID` value for a particular `Visitor_ID`. You would need to change the approach if you want different semantics for deciding which `Transaction_ID` to use.